# Convert dd/mm/yy string to yyyy-mm-dd

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am having issues converting a string in `dd/mm/yy hh:mi:ss` format to `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mi:ss` format.

I have tried using `CONVERT()` as follows:

```
select CONVERT(VARCHAR, '11/10/11 10:56:58', 120)
```

But that returns no change:

```
11/10/11 10:56:58
```

Comment: That's because converting with a style requires the data type to be either a `datetime` or `smalldatetime` (or `float`, `real`, `money`, or `smallmoney`, but that doesn't apply here), and you've provided it with a string. Plus, depending on the regional settings, it may not know how to convert `11/10/11`... is it October 11th or November 10th?

Comment: Please be careful about using `VARCHAR` without length. In case you didn't see it below: https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length.aspx

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to convert to datetime first to change a string to reflect a certain regional format. Be sure you are interpreting the datetime value correctly, too; on some systems, that will be October 11th, on others it will be November 10th.

```
SELECT CONVERT(CHAR(19), CONVERT(DATETIME, '11/10/11 10:56:58', 3), 120);
```

Finally, use the correct number of characters in your `char` or `varchar` declarations. Not specifying a length is lazy and can lead to problems. See:

- [Bad habits to kick : declaring VARCHAR without (length)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length)

Answer (score 4):

This will work:

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(19),CONVERT(DATETIME,'11/10/11 10:56:58',3),120)
```

Comment: @AaronBertrand yup, but you answer has an explanation

Answer (score 1):

The issue: you are converting a VARCHAR to a VARCHAR.

Your query is fine if you use a DATETIME.

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(19), CAST('11/10/11 10:56:58' AS DATETIME), 120);
```

See [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6f5e6/3).

Comment: Please read: https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length.aspx

Comment: @AaronBertrand: Thank you for sharing your blog post, but would that only affect uses of the `LEN` function (and such), and thus not affecting the use of this temporary variable?

Comment: Also this suffers the same problem - it makes assumptions that can lead to problems if the input string is ambiguous.

Comment: Well, if you want the output to be more than 30 characters (not that that is likely in this case), you'll have problems. But in general it's about promoting that practice in general - if you use it and recommend it here, people are likely to use it elsewhere, where it does cause problems.

Comment: @AaronBertrand: Good point. I'll encourage this practice from now on.